# Evaluate $ \iiint_S e^{-(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}} $ for $S=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2+z^2≤4, x>0, y>0, z>0\}$.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The given region is $S=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2+z^2≤4, x>0, y>0, z>0\}$, i.e. the first octant of the sphere with radius 2. The given integral has the form:

$$ \iiint_S e^{-(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}. $$

I'm wondering how can I obtain the upper boundaries for the variables for integrals and how to evaluate this in spherical coordinates.

The answer is $\dfrac{\pi}{6}(1-e^{-8})$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By setting $\rho^2=x^2+y^2+z^2$ we have that the purpose is to integrate $e^{-\rho^3}$ over the region given by the intersection of a solid sphere centered at the origin with radius $2$ and the positive octant. For any $r\in(0,2)$ the measure of the set $\{x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2,(x,y,z)>0\}$ is $\frac{\pi}{2}r^2$, hence by integrating along shells we get that the original integral equals

$$ \int_{0}^{2}\frac{\pi}{2} r^2 e^{-r^3}\,dr = \left.\frac{\pi}{6} e^{-r^3}\right|_{0}^{2} =\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{6}(1-e^{-8})}$$
and we're done.

Comment: Is this usable for all spheres where coordinate form is to be transformed to spherical coordinates?

Comment: @Grak: of course, the shell method applies in any dimension. In order to apply it, you just need to know the surface area of the $n$-dimensional unit sphere. In our case, $4\pi$, that gets divided by $8$ since we are considering the positive octant only.

Comment: Can I find the definition of this method by simply googling "shell method", because the mid-product seems a lot more neat than keeping it in three integrals

Comment: @Grak: a bit of googling does the job just fine. Anyway, we are just applying the main property of the Lebesgue integral of non-negative functions $$\int_{a}^{b} f(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\mu(x\in(a,b):f(x)\geq k) \, dk$$ that is Cavalieri's principle in disguise.

Answer (score 6):

$S$ is a filled in segment of a sphere of radius $2$. It's important to try to either draw or visualize the set over which you're integrating.

Since $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = \rho^2$, we have that $0 < \rho \leq 2$. Since $x,y,z>0$ the segment we're interested in lies in the first octant, so $0< \theta < \pi/2$ and $0 < \phi < \pi/2$ as well. This gives you
$$
\iiint_S e^{-(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}} \, dV =\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^2 e^{-(\rho^2)^{3/2}} \rho^2 \sin{\phi} \, d\rho \, d\theta \, d\phi. 
$$

Comment: This is also the right answer, but I highlighted the other solution because the mid-tier function was neater in that solution, but thanks anyway and have an updoot! :)